# Не удается сделать выгрузку файла на локальный ftp-сервер Docker

Tags: php, docker, localhost, containers

Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/upload/1.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/up_download.php on line 11

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpchNoD5' to 'upload/upload/1.png' in /var/www/html/up_download.php on line 11

PHP-код:

```
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
$file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$file_tem_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$file_store = "upload/upload/".$file_name;         


if (move_uploaded_file($file_tem_loc, $file_store)) {
    echo "Фото  '".$file_name."'  загружено в папку Upload";
}
```

}

Когда запускаю через: php -S localhost:8080 то все работает.

FTP-сервер - это просто локальная папка на маке.
Если напрямую в нее перетащить файл, то его видно и можно использовать, а вот положить туда не удается.
Как решить проблему?

Comment: во-первых, лучше указывать всё-таки абсолютный путь к файлу (в файловой системе, доступной из контейнера), а во-вторых, вы не забыли примонтировать каталог из хост-системы внутрь контейнера (т.н. «docker volumes»)?

Comment: можно более развернуто про: "вы не забыли примонтировать каталог из хост-системы внутрь контейнера (т.н. «docker volumes»)? "
Я не понял

Comment: ключевых слов недостаточно? извольте: [ссылка](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) (первая при поиске ключевых слов «docker volumes»).